# How do I properly pass a texture2d_array<float> to the fragment shader?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, macos, metal

Here's my fragment shader.

```
constexpr sampler ColorSampler;
fragment half4 T(VertexOut Vertex [[stage_in]], texture2d_array<float> Texture [[texture(0)]]) {
    return half4(Vertex.Color, 1)*half4(Texture.sample(ColorSampler, Vertex.TexCoord.xy/Vertex.TexCoord.z, 0));
}
```

This compiles. However, how do I pass a `texture2d_array<float>` from the Swift side that this shader will accept? I have a variable called `Textures` of type `[MTLTexture?]`, but how do I pass that as an array to texture buffer 0? This doesn't work.

```
CommandEncoder.setFragmentTextures(Textures, range: 0..<Textures.count)
```

It doesn't work because it's putting each texture in the texture buffer of its index. How do I properly pass a texture array to the fragment function?

How do I do it?

And is what I'm trying a good idea even?

And how am I expected to research if almost no in-depth content about this exists?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setFragmentTextures does indeed bind each texture individually.
If you want to use texture2d_array in your shader you'd have to create a MTLTexture with MTLTextureType [type2DArray](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtltexturetype/type2darray).

Comment: That's nice to know, and thanks for your response, but how exactly do I create an MTLTexture with that type?

Comment: Create a MTLTextureDescriptor (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtltexturedescriptor) and set the textureType property. Then, use this descriptor to create a texture array on the MTLDevice through https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice/1433425-maketexture

Comment: `let TextureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(pixelFormat: View.colorPixelFormat, width: 16, height: 16, mipmapped: Settings.Mipmaps > 0)
        TextureDescriptor.mipmapLevelCount = 4
        TextureDescriptor.textureType = MTLTextureType.type2DArray`?

Comment: What do I pass to setFragmentTexture()? I appreciate the help, but what would the implementation look like?

Comment: How do I load textures directly into the MTLTexture of type type2DArray

Comment: Apple developer side comes with sophisticated examples. This one uses texture 2d arrays, for example: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/rendering_terrain_dynamically_with_argument_buffers

Comment: I didn't find that example before but wow, thanks, I'll study and learn from it